# Clear radio input from React parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

having some issues trying to clear the radio input when I cycle through some questions. This is the setup I have. The want to setCheckedFalse to clear all answers when I click the button which triggers "handleNextQuestion". Currently I simply cannot click on any answers as they seem to be locked as false.

```
const Survey = () => {
    const setCheckedFalse = () => {
        return true
    }

    const handleNextQuestion = () => {
        if(currentQuestion < questions.length - 1) {

            const answer = {questionId: survey.id, answer: selectedAnswer};
            setSavedAnswers(savedAnswers => [...savedAnswers, answer])
            setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1)
            setCheckedFalse(true)
            setAnswer('')
        }
    }
    return (
    <div className="section">
        <div className="container">
            <div className={styles.surveyContainer}>   
                <Answers
                    answers = {survey}
                    selected = {selectedAnswer}
                    handleClick = {handleClick}
                    setCheckedFalse = {setCheckedFalse}
                />
                <button className="button is-primary" onClick={handleNextQuestion}>Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
const Answers = (props) => {
return (
    <>
        <div className={styles.itemList}>
            <label className={styles.labelWrapper}>
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="answer" 
                    className={styles.customRadio} 
                    onClick={props.handleClick}
                    value="a"
                    checked={props.setCheckedFalse}
                />
                <span>{props.answers.answer_a}</span>
            </label>
            <label className={styles.labelWrapper}>
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    name="answer" 
                    className={styles.customRadio} 
                    onClick={props.handleClick}
                    checked={props.setCheckedFalse}
                    value="b"
                />
                <span>{props.answers.answer_b}</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Could you provide an online demo for that?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue:

```
const setCheckedFalse = () => {
        return true
}
```

and

```
setCheckedFalse(true)
```

I think you're trying to change the state using what `useState` hook gives you but instead, you're calling a normal function that doesn't accept any arguments and nothing cares about the value it's returning.